# TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable when using lambda function in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997779/replace-values-greater-than-limit-using-lambda-in-multiple-observational-feature), I have this dataframe:

```
    ChildID   MotherID   preWeight
0     20      455        3500
1     20      455        4040
2     13      102        NaN
3     702     946        5000
4     82      571        2000
5     82      571        3500
6     82      571        3800
```

where I transformed feature 'preWeight' that has multiple observations per MotherID to feature 'preMacro' with a single observation per MotherID, based on the following rules:

- if preWeight>=4000 for a particular MotherID, I assigned preMacro a value of "Yes" regardless of the remaining observations
- Otherwise I assigned preMacro a value of "No"

Using this line of code:

```py
    df.groupby(['ChildID','MotherID']).agg(lambda x: 'Yes' if (x>4000).any() else 'No').reset_index().rename(columns={"preWeight": "preMacro"})
```

However, I realised that this way I am not preserving the NaN values in the dataset, which ideally should be imputed rather than just assigning them "No" values. So I tried changing the above line to:

```py
    df=df.groupby(['MotherID', 'ChildID'])['preWeight'].agg(
        lambda x: 'Yes' if (x>4000).any() else (np.NaN if 'no_value' in x.values.all() else 'No')).reset_index().rename(
        columns={"preWeight": "preMacro"})
```

I wanted this line to transform the above dataframe to this:

```
    ChildID   MotherID   preMacro
0   20        455        Yes
1   13        102        NaN
2   702       946        Yes
3   82        571        No
```

However I got this error when running it:

**TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable**

I understand that, in the case of non-missing values, the values of x.values.all() are float numbers, which are not iterable, but I am not sure how else to code this, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance dont test in custom function per groups, better is aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by helper column for boolean mask with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and
[`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) and then set column `preMacro` by [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df = (df.assign(testconst = df['preWeight'] > 4000,
                testna = df['preWeight'].notna())
        .groupby(['ChildID','MotherID'], sort=False)
        .agg({'testconst':'any', 'testna':'all'}))


masks = [df['testconst'] & df['testna'], df['testconst'] | df['testna']]
df['preMacro'] = np.select(masks, ['Yes','No'], default=None)
df = df.drop(['testconst','testna'], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   ChildID  MotherID preMacro
0       20       455      Yes
1       13       102     None <- for avoid convert np.NaN to string nan is used None
2      702       946      Yes
3       82       571       No
```

If small DataFrame or performance is not important:

```
f = lambda x: 'Yes' if (x>4000).any() else ('No' if x.notna().all() else np.NaN)
df1 = (df.groupby(['ChildID','MotherID'], sort=False)['preWeight']
         .agg(f)
         .reset_index(name='preMacro'))
print (df1)
   ChildID  MotherID preMacro
0       20       455      Yes
1       13       102      NaN
2      702       946      Yes
3       82       571       No
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried the second option and it works for me, but I understand what you are saying about its performance issues. I am quite new to Python and have not used boolean masks on dataframes before but will look into this method.